# Anyone know of a translation patch for Xenoblade?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I've been looking around for translation patches for Xenoblade and The Last Story for a while now. Seeing as Xenoblade has been out in Japan for a little while now I figure there must be a patch for it by now.

To my knowledge there is a Italian patch for the game at the moment, which makes me think that there must be an English one.

Anyone have any information about a menu/subtitle patch for Xenoblade? I'm sure there must be one either in the works or completed.

Answer (score 2):

In the years since this question was asked, Xenoblade Chronicles has had official English releases on Wii, Wii U, and New 3DS, making a translation patch unnecessary.

This was in part thanks to [Operation Rainfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Rainfall), a fan campaign started to encourage Nintendo to localize and release [Xenoblade Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenoblade_Chronicles), [The Last Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Story), and [Pandora's Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora%27s_Tower).

#### Xenoblade Chronicles, Wii

- **Japan**: 10 June 2010
- **Europe (*English*)**: 10 August 2011
- **Australia (*English*)**: 1 September 2011
- **North America (*English*)**: 6 April 2012

#### [Xenoblade Chronicles 3D](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-3d-3ds), New 3DS

- **Japan**: 2 April 2015
- **Europe (*English*)**: 2 April 2015
- **North America (*English*)**: 10 April 2015

#### [Xenoblade Chronicles](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-wii-u), Wii U

- **Europe (*English*)**: 5 August 2015
- **North America (*English*)**: 28 April 2016

---

#### Sources

- [Nintendo America: Xenoblade Chronicles Wii U](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-wii-u)
- [Nintendo America: Xenoblade Chronicles 3D](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-3d-3ds)
- [Nintendo Europe: Xenoblade Chronicles 3D](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Games/New-Nintendo-3DS/Xenoblade-Chronicles-3D-961136.html)
- [Nintendo Everything: Xenoblade Chronicles (Wii) out now on the European Wii U eShop](http://nintendoeverything.com/xenoblade-chronicles-wii-out-now-on-the-european-wii-u-eshop/)
- [Wikipedia: Xenoblade Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenoblade_Chronicles)

Answer (score 1):

So I spent a little time looking into this and I found out the following:

A patch does exist if you run the iso in an emulator (given the policies here I'm not going to link you, but I have confidence you can find it, just start by looking for an Italian patch).

If you want to avoid an emulator (for obvious reasons), then your next best bet is to wait until Xenoblade is released in NA.  It is still on Nintendo's calender for 2011.

If you can't wait, there is a subtitled walkthrough on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FiGLGFjCPM)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an English copy, remember that America isn't the only place to make English translations of games. Usually you can get a European copy or an Australian copy before the game is released in America. Generally, European copies will run on a normal Wii, but if you have any trouble try looking for an application for modded Wiis called RegionFrii which will allow you to convert the game to NTSC-U format, which is used in American copies.