# Can Space Eagles be earned?

Tags: angry-birds-space

In Angry Birds: Space, can you earn Space Eagles without purchasing them? The Game Center achievement reads like you have to purchase them, and there are other achievements tied to the Space Eagle. I'm wondering if you have to purchase them to complete the other achievements tied to the Space Eagle.

Comment: I know that's how it is in normal Angry Birds but I haven't played Space

Comment: @BenBrocka Purchasing is definitely different from the original's Mighty Eagle. Instead of purchasing it once and getting unlimited uses, it appears you can purchase uses of a Space Eagle (20 uses for $0.99, up to 980 for the low price of $19.99). Hooray for microtransactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: So far I've earnt 6 space eagles (in batches of three each time) through gameplay/3 star levels.

I've currently completed up to 2-11 and they did seem to come at major points: first unlocked golden egg/ 10 worlds and after the first boss fight.

Comment: Finally got to sit down and play and am seeing the same. I can't figure out if it's 3 stars or if it's from completing certain checkpoints. I got 3 after 10 levels (7 3-starred), and 3 after completing the first world , Pig Bang (8 3-starred). With that, seems like it may be checkpoint related rather than 3-stars.

Comment: That sounds fairly reasonable

Answer (score 2):

You get 10 eagles for getting 3 stars for every level in the first chapter, I assume you would get the same for the others

Answer (score 0):

I beat lvl 1-10with 1 bird and it gave me 23 eagles. Probably an Easteregg

Answer (score -2):

You can earn them by completing a lot of 3 star levels, (all from the beginning) and getting the birdsteriod. But you'll only get 3 that way in all your gameplay.

This is an screenshot from my game

[image]

Comment: Highly recommended that you remove the part where you encourage stealing.

Comment: "Piracy, and support with pirated games." is prohibited per the FAQ. Leave the part about the stealing out or this will likely be deleted if you keep editing it back in.

Comment: I've received two rewards of 3 so far through gameplay, etc., so 3's clearly not the maximum you can earn.

Comment: It's a stretch to call "regular" copyright infringement stealing. Incrementing a counter? Not a chance. What if there was a glitch that allowed you to get them? Is talking about the glitch allowed? Is talking about mods involving undocumented APIs allowed? There's no difference between this and [questions about infringing patches](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16418/).